# Service worker can't fetch assets offline

Tags: node.js, angular, service-worker, offline, offline-caching

I'm trying to make my website work offline, but it doesn't seem to work.
My project is based on node.js with external js files generated by angular.

It all seems to work fine, when the server is running and I go to localhost:3000, the service worker is installed correctly, then if I go to the Application tab in the Chrome Devtools, and I check "Offline" and I reload the page, it also works.

But if I turn off my server and I reload the page, I get the following error in my console: `An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.`

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/dist/favicon.ico">
    <link href="/dist/assets/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
  <script src="/client.js"></script>
  <script src="/service-worker.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="/dist/polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="/dist/runtime-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="/dist/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="/dist/styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="/dist/styles-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="/dist/vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="/dist/main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="/dist/vendor-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="/dist/main-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

client.js:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
             .register('./service-worker.js')
             .then(function() { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); });
}
```

service-worker.js:

```
var cacheName = 'myCacheVersion';
var filesToCache = [
    '/dist/favicon.ico',
    '/dist/runtime-es2015.js',
    '/dist/polyfills-es2015.js',
    '/dist/runtime-es5.js',
    '/dist/polyfills-es5.js',
    '/dist/styles-es2015.js',
    '/dist/styles-es5.js',
    '/dist/vendor-es2015.js',
    '/dist/main-es2015.js',
    '/dist/vendor-es5.js',
    '/dist/main-es5.js',
    '/client.js',
    '/service-worker.js',
];


self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Any idea on why it doesn't work?

Here is what I have in the console when I'm in the fake offline mode:
[image]

And here is what I have when I'm really offline
[image]

Comment: Check in the network tab, which script is failing to be loaded.

Comment: It's failing to get the route I'm in (http://localhost:3000/login)

Comment: yes, add the screenshot of your console and network tab

Comment: I added them to the post

Comment: are you killing the server which is running on 3000?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: never cache service-worker.js! Remove it from the files to cache. The browser has a local copy of it available and that one will be used as long as the browser updates the script from the server. There should never be a reason to put the script in the cache managed by SW. This, `<script src="/service-worker.js"></script>`, is also something you're not supposed to do. service-worker.js should not be included via regular script tags but only via the `navigator.serviceWorker.register(...)` call, as you do in your other file :)

You're getting the error because your browser, through Service Worker, is trying to load the root of your server and it's not available. Loading that results in a not available error and it's also not found in yuor Service Worker's cache because you're not caching it (not listed in the files to cache).

I really wonder how this code you provided can actually work offline at all since it's not caching your root page. It should not work offline at all – the Service Worker is NOT caching the root and hence should not be able to get anything from the cache while offline.

*It is worth nothing* that browsers having no connection (offline) and the website being unavailable (server down) are two completely different scenarios. In the former the SW knows that the network is not available and can take that into consideration when deciding how to response (if told so). In the latter, however, the browser is trying to get something from the network – which itself is working – but the destination itself is unavailable. This is a failure in connecting to the site, not offline mode. In the latter the SW has to decide how to handle, maybe fallback to an offline.html placeholder page, and most notably not cache the response.